# how to display an opencv image in vscode for mac

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a student working on a computer vision project. I need to see what the preprocessed image looks like. my problem is the preprocessed image is not showing in vscode, even though the file is running without any errors. I wonder whether I need to use an extension to view this or am I missing something here?

```
 kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7, 7))
 opening = cv2.morphologyEx(dist, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
 cv2.imshow("Opening", opening)
 k = cv2.waitKey(0)
 if k == 27 or k == ord('q'):
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with vscode. vscode is an editor. -- `imshow` opens its own window. show exactly how you run the program. learn to debug python programs. it's simple but you have to do it. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: This works well in vscode, and there is no problem whether it is run directly or in debug mode.You need to add your questions to better explain the problem. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZAnq.png